# What would be the best way to randomly select x values from a vector of u16 in Anchor program?

Tags: anchor, random

I'm creating an Anchor program where I'm storing an array containing other account IDs as u16 values. The array is a attribute in a seperate PDA. I want to create an instruction that randomly selects, let's say, 50% of of the items in that array. How can I achieve this? I know Switchboard has VRF, but I couldn't quite understand it nor understand how to implement it in my case properly.

This is my PDA Account storing u16 arrays from which I want to select x amount of random values:

```
#[account]
#[derive(Default)]
pub struct Lottery {
    pub id: u16,
    pub authority: Pubkey,
    pub all_user_ids: Option<Vec<u16>>,
    pub winner_ids: Option<Vec<u16>>,
}
```

Comment: Randomness is a very hard problem on-chain, since every node in the network must execute the transaction in the same way. If you really want randomness, you'll need to develop your own source of fair randomness, or rely on some other service like Switchboard. Here's a walkthrough for setting it up https://github.com/switchboard-xyz/vrf-demo-walkthrough